# File download not working in react native for IOS

Tags: react-native, download

I am using "react-native-fetch-blob" version 0.10.8 to download files in react-native . This is working as expected for android. I am able to download the files as expected. Where as for ios i am not able to download the files.

Below is the code i am using.

```
  downloadFinalBlog() {
const { config, fs } = RNFetchBlob;
let PictureDir = fs.dirs.PictureDir; 
let options = {
  fileCache: true,
  addAndroidDownloads: {
    useDownloadManager: true, 
    notification: false,
    title: "Great ! Download Success ! :",
    mime: "application/pdf",
      description: "Final Blog"
  }
};
config(options)
   .fetch("GET", "http://www.example.com/example.pdf")

  .then(res => {
     console.log(res);

  }).catch((error) => {

    console.log(error);
  });
```

}

Can anyone suggest me is there any other way to download files in IOS in react native.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi had got the answer to this but forgot to answer it here.

For ios We need to use openDocument inside the `then` which prompts the user to save the file to all available apps.

Please use below code:

```
.then(resp => {
      // console.log(resp);
      if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
        RNFetchBlob.ios.openDocument(resp.data);
      }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

For iOS use react-native-share module instead `RNFetchBlob.ios.openDocument(resp.data);`

[I have mentioned at here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77318983/11762907)

Answer (score -1):

this is due to App Transport Security. Your download link is on non secure http protocaol. You have to make exception in Info.plist. This exception will remain even in production build.
In project-directory/ios/project-name/Info.plist add these lines below

```js
<key>example.com</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
 <true/>
</dict>
```

Now NSAppTransportSecurity key must look like this

```js
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
 <dict>
  <key>example.com</key>
  <dict>
   <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
   <true/>
  </dict>
    <key>localhost</key>
  <dict>
   <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
   <true/>
  </dict>
 </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: Hi Arun kumar thanks for the suggestion. I tried but still the same result. same code is working for android. and for IOS the console log tells me the download has worked well, but not able to find the file.