# React native fetch blob not downloading image on iOS

Tags: react-native, camera-roll, rn-fetch-blob

I am trying to download image using `rn-fetch-blob` library but it is not getting downloaded from my server. The same code is working well with android but not on iOS. I am also using camera roll to save the image in the gallery but it is throwing the error `Could not find image` . What am I doing wrong?

Download code

```
   function DownloadImage(url,id){
    let imgUrl = url;

    let newImgUri = imgUrl.lastIndexOf('/');
    let imageName = imgUrl.substring(newImgUri);
    let dirs = RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs;
    let path = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? dirs['DownloadDir'] + imageName : dirs.PictureDir + imageName;   
        RNFetchBlob.config({
          fileCache: true,
          appendExt: 'png',
          path: path,
    
        }).fetch("GET", imgUrl).then(res => {
         CameraRoll.save(res.path()).then(()=>{
            }).catch((ex)=>{
                alert("Error="+ex);
            });
        }).catch(error=>{
            obj.loadingflag=false;
            alert(error);
        });
        
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

ifaced the same issue on IOS.
solution is  on response you have to do this

```
.then(resp => {
      // console.log(resp);
      if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
        RNFetchBlob.ios.openDocument(resp.data);
      }
    })
```

you can refer my answer [stack overflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60052019/rn-fetch-blob-download-docx-or-pdf-from-url-in-ios)

Comment: does this `RNFetchBlob.ios.openDocument(resp.data)` need to be before camera roll.save? Because I tried doing that and even though a blank document I being opened but I am still getting the error on camera roll.save